# Mute section of single audio stream in file with multiple streams using ffmpeg

Tags: audio, ffmpeg

I'm trying to mute a portion of the second audio stream in an mp4 file and it doesn't seem to do anything.

What I currently have is this:
`ffmpeg -i "2020-02-26 17-57-26.mp4" -filter_complex "[0:2]volume=enable='between(t,1,13)':volume=0[0:2]" -map 0:0 -map 0:1 -map 0:2 -c:v copy -c:a aac -b:a 320k "output.mp4"`

I'm completely lost on what's wrong with it

Answer (score 0):

Your mapping needs to be changed:

```
ffmpeg -i "2020-02-26 17-57-26.mp4" -filter_complex "[0:a:1]volume=enable='between(t,1,13)':volume=0[a1]" -map 0:v -map 0:a:0 -map "[a1]" -c:v copy -c:a:0 copy -c:a:1 aac -b:a 320k "output.mp4"
```

- Using a [stream specifier](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Stream-specifiers-1) will be more accurate. Using `[0:a:1]` will only select the second audio stream while `[0:2]` will select the third stream in the file regardless of type (video, audio, subtitle, data).
- Use custom label for your filter output (`[a1]` in the example) so it doesn't conflict with the generic `file index:stream index` scheme.

See the [`-map`](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Advanced-options) option for more info.